# pointcloud_to_laserscan, how to change the slice height

Tags: ros, laser, pointcloud-to-laserscan, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am running the *pointcloud_to_laserscan* package successfully with a Kinect. Now I want to change the height/angle at which the laser takes the slice from the pointcloud. Probably I am missing something, but none of the parameters described in
[http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan]
do what I want. I supposed that the parameters **min_height** and **max_height** were defined for this. But in stead, this parameters only select the points of the slice that are within this height range. Any guess?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259599/pointcloud_to_laserscan,-how-to-change-the-slice-height/) by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having just looked at the code; the height parameters seem to slice in the pointcloud orthogonal to the z axis in the height interval between min_height and max_height.

There are the parameters angle_min and angle_max, they are referring to the width of the simulated laserscan. So, that is not what you are looking for either.

I guess you may need to transform the pointcloud that are going into the pointcloud_to_laserscan, maybe just changing the reference frame.

---

Originally posted by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) with karma: 139 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-20**:
Indeed no such parameter, how about forking the code and adding one? (I could use it as well sometimes soon)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Humplestilzzchen - no need to fork, Karl was spot on

You can control the planar slice in the z-axis with the frame you output to via the target_frame param. In my case I was looking for objects at 6ft high so I created a static transform in my launch file:

```
<arg name="laser_height" default="1.829" /> <!-- 1.829m == 6ft -->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"' name="laser_height_offset" args="0 0 $(arg laser_height) 0 0 0 /base_link /laser_height 100 />
```

This creates the /laser_height frame in tf. Then in the config for pointcloud_to_laserscan I have:

```
<node pkg="pointcloud_to_laserscan" type="pointcloud_to_laserscan_node" name="scan">
  <remap from="cloud_in" to="your/Pointcloud2/topic/name" />
  <rosparam>
    target_frame: laser_height
    ...other params here...
  </rosparam>
</node>
```

Now you should have a laserscan slice at the level specified by the laser_height param (6ft / 1.829m in my case above).

The min_height and max_height params look like they define a band of points from the pointcloud to operate on; anything outside is ignored.

Thanks Karl!

---

Originally posted by [jdwolk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40613/jdwolk/) with karma: 21 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1